# rule for :: operator in c++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I think that the `::` operator can be unary in the case of accessing the global scope. In all other cases `::` is treated as a binary operator, and the evaluation rule for the `::` operator in the case of `N1::N2::N3::n` is equivalent to the following:

```
((N1::N2)::N3)::n // Error: ::n has not been declared
```

But that line doesn't compile. It is very curious. There is not any information in the standard about the evaluation of `nested-name-specifier`. It would be natural if the evaluation of `nested-name-specified` is equivalent to `qualified/unqualified-id`, **but it does not say this anywhere in the standard.** So can we assume that evaluation of a `nested-name-specifier` is implementation-dependent?

Comment: The standard defines `nested-name-specifier` right below where it defines `qualified-id`. And parentheses are not involved in that definition.

Comment: @Sneftel you're right. But what about rule of evaluation?

Comment: @No, I'm looking for action subsequent to determine what entity denoted by nested-name-specifier?

Comment: There is no evaluation. The scope resolution operator has no priority and associativity. The expression `a::(b::c)` as opposed to `(a::b)::c` has no sense. Nor has `a::(b + c)`.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy How to determine an entity denoted by nested-name-specifier?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, Doesn't [basic.lookup.qual] describe that?

Comment: AFAICS `((N1::N2)::N3)::n` is always a parse error, but for instance `(N1::N2)::n` would actually compile assuming there's a type `N1::N2` and a global variable `n`, and if `n` is convertible to `N1::N2`! It would just mean a completely different thing than `N1::N2::n`. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scope resolution operator `::` is right-associative because the recursive grammar of the *nested-name-specifier* production is right-associative:

```
nested-name-specifier:
    ::[opt] type-name ::
    ::[opt] namespace-name ::
    decltype-specifier ::
    nested-name-specifier identifier ::
    nested-name-specifier template[opt] simple-template-id ::
```

The appropriate rule for recursively evaluating a *nested-name-specifier* is then 3.4.3 **[basic.lookup.qual]**:

> 1 - The name of a class or namespace member or enumerator can be referred to after the `::` scope resolution operator (5.1) applied to a *nested-name-specifier* that denotes its class, namespace, or enumeration. [...]

Importantly, unlike 5.1, which only discusses lookup of *qualified-id*s (in 5.1.1p8), 3.4.3p1 is unrestricted and so can be used to lookup *nested-name-specifier*s recursively.

That is, in:

```
namespace A {
    namespace B {
        struct C {
            struct D {
                static int i;
            };
        };
    }
}
A::B::C::D::i;
```

`A::B::C::D::i` is parsed as a *qualified-id* containing recursively the *nested-name-specifier*s `A::B::C::D::`, `A::B::C::`, `A::B::`, and `A::`.  Now, to evaluate `A::B::C::D::i`:

- we use 5.1.1p8, which requires evaluation of `A::B::C::D`;
- we use 3.4.3p1, which requires evaluation of `A::B::C`;
- we use 3.4.3p1, which requires evaluation of `A::B`;
- we use 3.4.3p1, which requires evaluation of `A`.

Now we have to find a sense in which `A` "*denotes*" a "*class, namespace or enumeration*".  In the absence of anything more specific, section 3 refers us to 3.4:

> 1 - The name lookup rules apply uniformly to all names (including *typedef-name*s (7.1.3), *namespace-name*s (7.3), and *class-name*s (9.1)) wherever the grammar allows such names in the context discussed by a particular rule. [...]

The lookup of `A` now proceeds according to the rules of 3.4.1 **[basic.lookup.unqual]** as applied to the particular context.  Since we are in global scope, 3.4.1p4 applies and we search global scope for name `A`.  We find the namespace `A`, and evaluation of `A::B::C::D::i` proceeds accordingly.

---

That is, the *leftmost* (innermost) name in a *nested-name-specifier* is looked up as an unqualified name; successive names are looked up as qualified names on their inner *nested-name-specifier*.

Answer (score 9):

In `[expr.prim.general]` (5.1.1/8-9) the parsing rules of `::` are listed. It requires that `::` is followed by the name of a namespace/class or the name of a member of a namespace/class. `(` and `)` are not allowed.

More specifically in `[over.oper]` (13.5/1) the standard defines `operator-function-id` and `operator` as one of `new`, `delete`, `+`, `-`, `!`, `=`, `ˆ=`, `&=`, `<=`, `>=`, `()`, `[]`, `new[]`, `*`, `<`, `|=`, `&&`, `delete[]`, `/`, `>`, `<<`, `||`, `%`, `+=`, `>>`, `++`, `ˆ`, `-=`, `>>=`, `--`, `&`, `*=`, `<<=`, `,`, `|`, `/=`, `==`, `->*`, `∼`, `%=`, `!=`, `->`.

`.`, `.*`, `::`, `?:` are named as an exception in clause 9 to not act as ordinary unary or binary operators.

Comment: If the LHS of `::` denotes a class, the RHS is a member of that class, not a member of a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing implementation dependent. You are incorrectly assuming it's an operator, though. It's not. Therefore, it's neither a unary nor a binary operator, and it does not form expressions. And since it doesn't form expressions, there's no evaluation of those expressions.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly so. The standard calls `::` the *scope resolution operator*.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy So :: is operator or it is not?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, It depends on how you define the terminology. The standard does call it operator.

Comment: It is an operator - but one that is resolved at compile time.

Comment: it lies on top of the [precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc : That's a non-standard table. Useful for some, but not an authoritative source.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: See Danvil's quote. The fact that something is called an X-Foo if the grammar doesn't mean it's also a Foo. In particular, the _scope resolution operator_ is not an _operator_. (We had earlier issues with "template classes" which weren't classes, but that bit has been cleaned up by renaming them to class templates - they are templates.)

Comment: @MSalters, Thank you for input but that's a debatable point. The exact quotation from C++'03 (C++'11 is not available to me at the moment but I doubt that it differs in that matter) is: 'The following operators cannot be overloaded: `.` `.*` `::` `?:`'. That is, these four *are* operators from the point of view of the standard, though with some special features: in this case, in respect to operator overloading.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: Clause 9 states "Operators not mentioned explicitly in subclauses 13.5.3 through 13.5.7 act as ordinary unary and binary operators obeying the rules of 13.5.1 or 13.5.2.". Moreover in clause 1 it defines *operator* as the list I mentioned, in the sense that they mimic a function. Other sections regarding operators refer to this section, so it is not only about overloading.

Comment: @MSalters I'd go with Andrey on this one. -1 because you a) don't provide any sourcing of your statement in actual specs, b) seem very sure you're right, although what you say doesn't follow the spec in a straightforward manner, making if feel like an *opinion*, not a *fact*, c) I've always considered :: an operator just because the spec and a lot of books/manuals say so; if you consider it's the other way around, the burden of proof lies on you, not on the people disagreeing with out.

Comment: @Danvil, "Operators not mentioned explicitly in subclauses 13.5.3 through 13.5.7" -- exactly. Entities mentioned, among others, in subclause 13.5.3 *are* operators. "Moreover in clause 1 it defines *operator*" -- what it defines is the non-terminal symbol *operator* which is used in a particular place of the syntax. It does not define the term 'operator'. You cannot substitute one for another, for otherwise you will end up saying that `.*` or `?:` are not operators ether.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: Actually, that was the closest to a definition of the word "operator" I could find. I would be very interested if you know a clause in the standard which defines the term 'operator'. As far as I can see, it is used in a very unspecific way.

Comment: @Danvil, as far as I can see, the term 'operator' is not given a strict definition anywhere. Curiously, when discussing lexical conventions, the standard uses the term 'operators' and even refers to *operator* in the definition of *token*. However, that cannot be the same *operator* as in [over.oper] because the latter may be composed of several tokens! It also refers to *punctuator* but for that no definition can be found anywhere.

Comment: AFAICT the normative grammar contains `operator`, and there is no rule or sequence of rules such that `::` can be parsed as `operator`. That's the problem with people demanding a quotation: I can't prove a non-existance, but anyone can show a single counter-example in which `::` would be parsed as an `operator` merely by showing the rules used.

Comment: @MSalters, there's no way *operator* may generate `::`, yes. But on the other hand, a `+` may not be generated by *operator*. For example, in an expression like `x + y` there is no *operator*!